# selectize.js call href to add new option

Tags: selectize.js

The documentation of selectize already explains how to use create: function (input, callback) {....} to add a new item to the database.

In my case, the base model of a selectbox not only contains the option name but also other data.

P.e.: I have a selectbox with countries.
The options are filled from a model "Countries" which contains "country_name", "top_level", "currency". The selectbox only shows "country_name".
If a user wants to add a new country, I want to open a bootstrap modal, let the user add the new country data and after saving I want to refresh the selectbox using refreshOptions ().

I tried to change in selectize.js in line 741 from

```
'option_create': function(data, escape) {
    return '<div class="create">Add <strong>' + escape(data.input) + </strong>&hellip;</div>';
```

to

```
'option_create': function(data, escape) {
    return '<a data-toggle="modal" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static" data-target="#modal" href="... some link ...">New country</a>';
```

I can see the link after writing a not existing country in the seletbox but when I click on it nothing happens.

How can I fix this? I am already to close to give up :-)

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Javascript for removing option:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".chosen-search-94-departID").selectize({
      create: true,
      sortField: {field: 'text'},
      onOptionAdd: function (value, $item) { 
          var link='... link ...' + value;
          load_modal_content (link, '... csrf ...');
          $('#modal').modal('show');
          $item.selectize.removeOption(value);
      },
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be cleaner / simpler to use onItemAdd (see [Usage page](https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/usage.md)) to define a behavior when a new item is added. No need to change selectize.js for that, I think.

Comment: Thank you. It worked (nearly). But I still have a problem: When a user writes a new option, the modal view - where the user should add the new data for the option - opens.
Now the user decides not to add a new option. He closes the modal view but the new option still is selectable.
It there a way to stop selectize from adding a new option automaticly? If the option is really saved to the database, I would add it after closing the modal.

Comment: Then use removeItem() (and perhaps removeOption()) to eliminate the incomplete option.

Comment: Removing doesn't work. I am sure my code it not correct. Could you have a look? I added my code above. Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps you should set up some fiddle / plunk to show a simplified version of your code, so we can try to fix it. What you show is strange: all your options have a reference to the current Selectize instance? In general, when you call selectize() to attach it to a control, you get the instance via `.selectize(...).data('selectize')`